# How to Sync Queryable Metadata with Cloud Blob Storage

Tags: mongodb, architecture, neo4j, cloud

I am trying to understand the general architecture and components needed to link metadata with blob objects stored into the Cloud such as Azure Blob Storage or AWS.

Consider an application which allows users to upload a blob files to the cloud.  With each file there would be a miriade of metadata describing the file, its cloud URL and perhaps emails of users the file is shared with.

In this case, the file gets save to the cloud and the metadata into some type of database somewhere else.  How would you go about doing this transactionally so that it is guaranteed both the file was saved and the metadata? If one of the two fails the application would need to notify the user so that another attempt could be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in mechanism to span transactions across two disparate systems, such as Neo4j/mongodb and Azure/AWS blob storage as you mentioned. This would be up to your app to manage. And how you go about that is really a matter of opinion/discussion.